# Risk Maps - Spatial Analysis

Tags: spatial-analyst, overlay

I have created a basic mining subsidence likelihood map which contains the variables of depth and distance from lineament using the weighted overlay tool.

From these results I would like to create a Risk Map which takes into account types of road which intersect these areas. I would have different types of road e.g. major, minor, private etc. Each of these types of road would have a different consequence if it were subjected to subsidence. High consequence for major, low for minor.

I know that Risk = likelihood * consequence. So would I be able to just multiply the likelihood results with my reclassified road data or would it be better to include it in the Weighted Overlay analysis?